# PL/SQL constraint: Always one record in a table

Tags: sql, oracle

Im trying to add a constraint to a table so that there can only be one record in the table.

This is the code I already have:

```
ALTER TABLE CONFIG
ADD CONSTRAINT always_one 
CHECK (count(*)= 1);
```

And this is the error I'm getting

```
ALTER TABLE CONFIG
ADD CONSTRAINT always_one CHECK (count(*)= 1)
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00934: group function is not allowed here
00934. 00000 -  "group function is not allowed here"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

How does this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use already proposed solution with adding unique constraint on column

```
alter table config add constraint always_one check (pk_col=1);
```

this however allows inserting more than one row in case  pk_col is null in second inserted row. So you need to handle this by adding a NOT NULL constraint as well

```
ALTER TABLE config
ADD CONSTRAINT notnulc CHECK (pk_col IS NOT NULL) ;
```

To prevent deleting this row, you should probably create before delete trigger as follows

```
create or replace trigger trg_ONLYONE before delete ON CONFIG 

DECLARE
 C NUMBER;
BEGIN
   SELECT COUNT(*) INTO C FROM CONFIG;

      if  (C=1) THEN
        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR (-20011, 'TOO FEW ROWS');
      END IF;


END;
```

Futher options are: instead of check constraints mentioned above is CREATE BEFORE INSERT trigger, or instead of NOT NULL and UNIQUE CONSTRAINT make pk_col  PRIMARY KEY

Comment: Thx! This covers my question completely :D

Answer (score 1):

Just create a unique index on a column in the table, and add a constraint that the value of this column must be a certain value.

eg.

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX one_val ON config(pk_col);

ALTER TABLE CONFIG
ADD CONSTRAINT always_one 
CHECK (pk_col = 1);
```

If all of your other columns could be any value, you may need to just add this additional column, and give it a default value.

Comment: How does that prevent to remove "the" row from the table ?

Comment: It doesn't.  I kind of interpreted his question to be *at most one*, but a literal interpretation would demand that the last record can't be deleted.

Comment: Thx! This helped me a lot. Is there a way so you can not remove the record?